# HTML login not working

Tags: javascript, html, authentication

I am trying to make myself a login for my website, and I already tested that the links provided exist, and the redirect worked. I don't know why it isn't working!
Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>login2</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
    <input class="textBox" id="pass" type="password" maxlength="30" required/>
    <button type="button" onclick="a()">Login</button>
    <script>
        function a() {
            var i = document.getElementById('pass') if (i == "1234") {
                window.location = "in.html"
            } else {
                window.location =
                    "index.html"
            }

        }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I looked everywhere trying to figure out why it won't work. Please help me!

Comment: Sorry! Those '>' before each line were because of the text editor thing on this site!

Comment: Having formatted your code it's very obvious that you have extra `}`.

Comment: i request you to learn php login system first

Comment: You probably want to do: `i = document.getElementById('pass').value`, because `i` could never be `"1234"` in this case as your are getting a DOM object. Also please describe the exact problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this script instead; replace your entire script block; there were some missing semicolons.  And as @dfsq mentioned, and extra }.  And as @spencer said, you need .value to get the password text.

```
<script>
    function a() {
        var i = document.getElementById('pass').value;
        if (i == "1234") {
            window.location = "in.html";
        } 
        else {
            window.location = "index.html";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Note that I'd recommend not checking passwords on the client since it can be manipulated by client side tools.

Comment: Updated with more info.

Comment: Great! Just want to mention in JavaScript semi-colons are optional for the most part. Not having them will not harm the code.

Comment: Yes. I agree.  It improves readability, especially if you have more than one statement on a single line like it was originally.

Comment: Thank you!!!!! I know it isn't too secure, but it's a very basic little website I'm making. Thanks again, that really helped

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>login2</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="loginForm" method="post">
        <input class="textBox" id="pass" type="password" maxlength="30" required/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="login">
    </form>
    <script>
        $('#loginForm').on('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var i = $('#pass').val();
            if (i == "1234") {
                window.location = "in.html";
            } else {
                window.location = "index.html";
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The OP is not using jQuery.

Comment: jQuery for this kind of solution is an overkill, in this case it will decrease performance since it must loads the entire jQuery library.

Comment: If this form was the only thing he'd ever use - maybe, but I kind of doubt it. Besides, this is a much better and professional way of doing it than the one above.